# awk strftime to return timest

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm using this nifty one-liner to add a timestamp to each line of my logfile:

```
tail -f log  | grep -a --line-buffered "." | awk '{ print strftime("%s\t"), $0; fflush() }'
```

Unfortunately it only gives full seconds while I need millisecond resolution between the datapoints. Is there an equally elegant solution to get a ms timestamp? I don't care about the time since the epoch, only about the difference between the lines.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be surprised if `tail -f` works to millisecond accuracy. Does it? If not, you're wasting your time on the rest of it.

Comment: I'm actually using cat /dev/ttyUSB0 to log a serial data stream, I do hope that it logs with sub second resolution, I sample with 5Hz so nothing too crazy..

Comment: IIRC by default tail sleeps 1 second between iterations when used with `-f`. You can change it to a longer interval but you're not going to get it less than a second unless there's some GNU enhancement or something out there. Oh wait, are you saying that you DON'T use tail at all? Stating the obvious - you should post whatever command you're using, not some other command line you aren't using.

Comment: You have a point, but at least now I learned that tail has this delay and will not be tempted to use it in the future ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to replace the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `Time::HiRes` built-in module, like:

```
tail -f infile | perl -MTime::HiRes=time -ne 'printf "%.3f\t%s", time(), $_'
```

It yields something like:

```
1390014680.197  one
1390014680.197  two
1390014680.197  three
1390014680.197  four
1390014680.197  five
1390014680.197  six
1390014689.414  seven
1390014693.542  eight
```

Comment: I'd love to see it work without perl but this is exactly the format I want, the other options are great but the time format with day and hours is not useful in this case as I feed the data straight into matplotlib to plot over time. If date has a timestamp functions in pure ms or ns that would be great ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use your `awk` but need to change it some:

```
tail -f log  | grep -a --line-buffered "." | awk '{ print d, $0; fflush() }' d=$(date -Ins)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `awk` with `sed`, then use `$(date -Ins)` to add an ISO 8601 timestamp with nanosecond precision.

`tail -f infile | grep -a --line-buffered "." | sed 's/^/'"$(date -Ins)\t"'/'`

```
2014-01-18T17:24:08,110459605+1100  one
2014-01-18T17:24:08,110459605+1100  two
2014-01-18T17:24:08,110459605+1100  three
```

or `$(date --rfc-3339=ns)` for an alternate format:

`tail -f infile | grep -a --line-buffered "." | sed 's/^/'"$(date --rfc-3339=ns)\t"'/'`

```
2014-01-18 17:24:51.985434198+11:00 one
2014-01-18 17:24:51.985434198+11:00 two
2014-01-18 17:24:51.985434198+11:00 three
```